# Setting subject in ejs template for NestJS Mailer

Tags: nestjs, ejs, nodemailer

We're using NestJS Mailer, which is a wrapper for nodemailer, and (currently) EJS to send templated HTML emails from our application.

I would like for the the e-mail subject to be defined in the EJS template file, along with the rest of the message, but it seems the subject needs to be set in the message object.

Is there any way, using EJS or any other templating engine (e.g. handlebars), to set the subject in the template file, and have NestJS Mailer use that one?

Something along the lines of:

```js
Subject: 'Hello, subject!'

<html>
...etc
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a workaround, and while I'm not entirely content with it, it will do the job for now.

I'm still interested in alternative solutions - especially anything already built into either nodemailer, NestJS Mailer or a relevant templating engine.

My workaround is to create an extension to the NestJS Mailer `EjsAdapter` which adds a `setSubject()`-function to the context object. Then call this function from within the template:

```
export class EjsAdapterExtension extends EjsAdapter {
    public compile(mail: any, callback: any, mailerOptions: MailerOptions): void {
        if (mail && mail.data && mail.data.context) {
            mail.data.context.setSubject = (subject: string) => {
                mail.data.subject = mail.data.subject || subject || mailerOptions.defaults.subject;
            };
        }

        super.compile(mail, callback, mailerOptions);
    }
}
```

```js
<% setSubject('My template subject'); %>

<html>
...etc
</html>
```